# Два флажка. При выборе одного — снять флажок с другого

Tags: android, checkbox

В `main_menu.xml` есть два `CheckBox`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_menu1"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:title="Действие_1">
    <menu>
        <item android:checkable="true" android:id="@+id/menu1_open"
            android:title="Открыть" />
        <item android:checkable="true" android:id="@+id/menu1_close"
            android:title="Закрыть" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

В `MainActivity.java` следующий код:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu1_open:
            item.setChecked(item.isChecked() ? false : true);

            CheckBox ch = findViewById(R.id.menu1_close);
            ch.setChecked(false);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

И мне нужно переключать эти флажки, т.е если выбрал `menu1_open`, то `menu1_close` стал `false` и наоборот.

Но это строка `CheckBox ch = findViewById(R.id.menu1_close);` возвращает ошибку:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference`

И я не могу понять, почему так? Ведь `menu1_close` существует!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело?

p.s мне нужно использовать именно `CheckBox` (задание такое) и я совсем "зеленый" в java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку возвращает эта строка `ch.setChecked(false);`, потому что `ch` не найден и имеет значение null.

Для ссылок на элементы меню вместо

```
CheckBox ch = findViewById(R.id.menu1_close);
```

которое ищет вью в лейауте активити/фрагмента следует использовать:

```
MenuItem ch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu1_close);
```

Поскольку элемент меню - не чекбокс и не его наследник, его нельзя к нему привести в инициализации переменной, но он также может быть checkable и принимать состояние checked.

Если нужно использовать именно класс CheckBox, то стоит это делать не в меню, а в обычном активити/фрагменте.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.